# find object instance of model between two dates

Tags: python, django

i want the records of my purchase items. when i added the purchase items in purchase model, that data are shown in my another app records  have date time field start date to end date. if we added the two dates all the purchase data we purchase between these dates are shown in records. 
so please help me. thank you.

this below code is my project app name purchase, model name is PurchaseReport.

```
from django.db import models
from stock.models import *

class PurchaseReport(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    #status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Purchased')

    def save(self):
        if not self.pk:
            Stock.objects.create(product_name=self.product_name, quantity=self.quantity, price=self.price)
        super().save()

    def __str__(self):
    return 'Product name:{0} Quantity:{1} Price:{2}'.format(self.product_name, self.quantity, self.price)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['product_name']
```

and this my views.py of app purchase

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from .models import *
from stock.models import *
from .forms import *


def display_purchase_report(request):
    items_list = PurchaseReport.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        items_list = items_list.filter(product_name__icontains=query)
    paginator = Paginator(items_list, 5)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
        'object_list': items,
        'items': items_list,
        'header': 'PURCHASED ITEMS'
    }
    return render(request, 'index3.html', context)


def add_purchase_report(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PurchaseReportForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('display_purchase_report')

    else:
        form = PurchaseReportForm()
        return render(request, 'add_new3.html', {'form': form})
```

next is another app records and model name is Records.

```
from django.db import models
from purchase_report.models import *


class Records(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Start Date:{0} End Date:{1}' .format(self.start_date, self.end_date)
```

Comment: How do these `Records` and `Purchase` "relate" to each other? In your view you use an unspecified `PurchaseReport` object.

Comment: sorry i change the model name. but now i correct it.

Comment: but there seems to be *no* connection between `PuchaseReport` and `Records` here?

Comment: yes. because both are different app. that's why i ask the question. because i don't know what to do.

Comment: the fact that these are different apps does not make a difference, you can write foreign keys between models of different apps. Since your `PurchaseReport` has no date, there is not much we can "do" here, you can not filter on data you do not have.

Comment: you can add foreign key  Purchases  to the records but if all that you need is to filter the purchases by date check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## problem you can set the dates to the purchases and then filter them in date range

```
class PurchaseReport(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Then maybe make a `def make_purchase`

```
#just hook the date today to the purchase when create new 
def make_purchase(request):
    purchase = Purchase.object.create(
        product_name = request['product_name'],
        quantity = request['quantity'],
        price = request['price'],
        date = date.today()
    )
    purchase.save()
        
def display_purchase_report(request):
        report  = Purchases.objects.filter(date__range=["2018-10-01", "2011-11-1"])
        context = {'reports':report}
        return render(request, 'index3.html', context)
```

then in the template just do this like:

```
{% for record in records %}
    {{ record.product_name }}
    {{ record.quantity }}
{% endfor %}
```